# how to tell if a django user has EVER logged in?

Tags: django, authentication, registration

We have a Django project where a User account is created for a person whenever she calls us on the phone. The person may or may not, at a later point, use her account to log in to our website.

**Question: How can I tell if a User has *ever* logged in to our website?**

**Clarification: I want to answer the question above for hundreds of existing users, not just for new users that are created from this point on.**

**Thought 1:** Check `User.last_login`. Unfortunately Django initializes `last_login` to `datetime.datetime.now()` when the User is created, regardless of whether she ever logged in.

**Thought 2:** Check if `User.last_login` matches `User.date_joined`. Unfortunately Django initializes *both* these fields to `datetime.now()`, and they can be a few microseconds apart:

```
In [1]: u = User.objects.create(username="bla")

In [2]: u.date_joined - u.last_login
Out[2]: datetime.timedelta(0, 0, 23)
```

**Current hack I am using:** Assume the user has logged in at least once *iff* `user.last_login - user.date_joined >= datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)`.

Is there a better way to tell if a User has ever logged in?

Comment: You could use a User Profile to store the fact that they've really logged in at least once, or maybe you could simply log the fact.  Or perhaps use a post_save on the User object to set the last_login to None when the User is first created.

Comment: Yes, collecting this info for *new* users is not hard. But is there a way to recover this information about *existing* users? We don't have logs going far enough back, unfortunately. (Clarification added to original question.)

Comment: I think your current hack is probably the best approach.. I'd go so far as to not even call it a hack.  What don't you like about it?

Comment: @DMactheDestroyer, I call it a hack because of the arbitrary timedelta. Zero is clearly too little because of the microsecond problem described above. One minute might be too much, because a user can type in her password and log in within less than one minute of calling us, and then we will miss that login. One second seems reasonable, but is still somewhat arbitrary.

Comment: How do you normally track when a user logs in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you're right when you say that both the `date_joined` and `last_login` are set to the current date on creation, and that for some reason there is enough time elapsed between the two assignments to create a noticeable delta.

If that's the case, then you could take @LAK's advice and create either a [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-save) (and check if the instance's ID is 0) or [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) (and check the `created` parameter) and manually set the `last_login` field to either `None` or the same value as `date_joined`.  From there all of your future data is preserved from the one-second fuzziness you seem to despise.

As for your existing data, I think that you're stuck making the best guess with the data you've got.  I don't see it as too risky to make the assumption that you're making.  If you wanted to clean it up to be the same as all new data, you could just update your database to set the `last_login` value.  If you're using [South](http://south.aeracode.org/), this is easy enough to do with a data migration.  Otherwise, you could just create a script to run after you deploy the new code changes.

I honestly don't think that it's a problem that they're off by a little bit.  So long as you're making the assumption that it's most likely not humanly possible for a user to log in within the time frame that their account was created, there seems to be little reason to add a bunch of extra work to force it to be an exact match.

Comment: It doesn't work because last_login field does not accept null values.

Answer (score 4):

If newer versions of Django (> 1.8), you should use User.last_login. This is what the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/) states:

> last_login
>
> A datetime of the user’s last login.
>
> Changed in Django 1.8: This field will be null if the user has never
>   logged in. Previously it was set to the current date/time by default.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an `F` object to compare `last_login` with `date_joined`. If they're equal, then the user has never logged in (or at least never logged in after their initial signup, which is about the best you can determine)

```
from django.db.models import F

User.objects.filter(last_login=F('date_joined'))
```

**UPDATE**

Well, it successfully worked in my environment, but I suppose it is *possible* the two could be off by a few microseconds or more. If that's the case, then I think your only recourse is to actually manually check each `User`. You can do variations on the following if you need greater accuracy, but generally, I think a user who has never logged in after the day they initially created the count could be counted as "never logged in" for all intents and purposes -- either way, they've abandoned the account.

```
if user.date_joined.date() == user.last_login.date():
    # do something
```

If you need greater accuracy:

```
date_joined = datetime.combine(user.date_joined.date(), time(user.date_joined.hour, user.date_joined.minute))
last_login = datetime.combine(user.last_login.date(), time(user.last_login.hour, user.last_login.minute))
if date_joined == last_login:
    # do something
```

That essentially creates new datetime objects, removing the differences on seconds and microseconds. Surely a 1 minute accuracy level is good enough here.

Comment: Using `F` expressions is very elegant. Unfortunately this can break because of the microsecond delta described in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that can filter a `QuerySet` by users that either has or hasn't logged on the site.

The `filter_user_has_used_site()` and `filter_user_hasnt_used_site()` functions works on a `QuerySet` containing `auth.User`.

The `filter_resource_has_used_site()` and `filter_resource_hasnt_used_site()` works on any queryset which model has a `ForeignKey` field named `user` to `auth.User`.

It only works for mysql but can easily be made to support other database engines.

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db import connection

MYSQL = "ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,auth_user.last_login,auth_user.date_joined))"


def filter_resource_has_used_site(qs):
    """
    Takes a QuerySet of resources and returns a QuerySet only containing
    resources that has logged in to site at least once.
    """
    vendor = connection.vendor
    if vendor == 'mysql':
        # Force the orm to join to auth_user.
        qs = qs.filter(user__username__isnull=False)
        where = "".join([MYSQL, '>1'])
        return qs.extra(where=[where])
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError('Vendor type {} not supported.'.format(
            vendor))


def filter_resource_hasnt_used_site(qs):
    """
    Takes a QuerySet of resources and returns a QuerySet only containing
    resources that never logged in to site.
    """
    vendor = connection.vendor
    if vendor == 'mysql':
        # Force the orm to join to auth_user.
        qs = qs.filter(user__username__isnull=False)
        where = "".join([MYSQL, '<2'])
        return qs.extra(where=[where])
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError('Vendor type {} not supported.'.format(
            vendor))


def filter_user_has_used_site(qs):
    """
    Takes a QuerySet of users and returns a QuerySet only containing
    users that has logged in to site at least once.
    """
    vendor = connection.vendor
    if vendor == 'mysql':
        where = "".join([MYSQL, '>1'])
        return qs.extra(where=[where])
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError('Vendor type {} not supported.'.format(
            vendor))


def filter_user_hasnt_used_site(qs):
    """
    Takes a QuerySet of users and returns a QuerySet only containing
    users that never logged in to site.
    """
    vendor = connection.vendor
    if vendor == 'mysql':
        where = "".join([MYSQL, '<2'])
        return qs.extra(where=[where])
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError('Vendor type {} not supported.'.format(
            vendor))


def user_has_used_site(user):
    """
    Returns if a auth.user has logged into the site.
    """
    return abs(user.last_login - user.date_joined) > timedelta(seconds=1)
```